# "password authentication failed for user" after push to Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I followed the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) to install a django app and at first it worked fine. After a day I pushed some changes to the server. After that, I was not able to access the app at all: `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "drjstoymyqyarj"`

I can not even sync the db anymore:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 177, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "drjstoymyqyarj"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "drjstoymyqyarj"
```

I have used the database settings recommended in the heroku doc:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

When I check the logs after pushing code to the server, there is a suspicious `Process exited with status 143` that I did not notice before. Maybe that has something to do with it?

```
$ heroku logs
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:41048 --noreload`
app[web.1]: Validating models...
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: 0 errors found
app[web.1]: Django version 1.4, using settings 'ClosetList.settings'
app[web.1]: Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:41048/
app[web.1]: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

**[Edit]**
Same error msg with `heroku pg:psql`. I am however able to open a Django shell with `heroku run python manage.py shell`, but I can not access any data from within it (same error of course).
**[/Edit]**

any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Have you test to log in into database from `heroku pg:psql` command? Also, can you open a shell: `heroku run python manage.py shell` ? Have you double check that `DATABASES` variable is not initialized for twice? Also, Heroku is moving databases from old system to new one. Have you try to do this proces by hand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run

```
heroku config
```

and see if there are more than 2 heroku dbs configured and also see if DATABASE_URL point to your configured DB. If not, then you can promote your db to default DATABASE_URL by running:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN
```

Where HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN is your database name, you will see HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN_URL in your config.

Once your configured database is promoted to default database, you are ready to go.

Comment: i can't really test that now, because i recreated the app on heroku and it is runing fine now. your answer does look promising though. i'll try it in case i run into the problem again.

Comment: Actually, I ran into same problem yesterday and figure out this solution. :)

Comment: Just in case it helps, after running heroku config, I saw that my config var in heroku had a "hidden" space in the password, I have to add a character save the variable and then delete the variable, very odd but thanks to your comment i was able to see the space in the console